# Maven dependency, Piechart

Tags: maven, charts

I am using the program in this link:

https://www.javatips.net/api/dg-toolkit-master/web/src/main/java/org/devgateway/toolkit/web/excelcharts/data/XSSFPieChartData.java

to create Piechart, but I couldn't find the maven dependencies for these imports:

```
    import org.devgateway.toolkit.web.excelcharts.CustomChartSeries;
    import org.devgateway.toolkit.web.excelcharts.util.XSSFChartUtil;
```

Comment: They don't seem to be available from maven central. Maybe you could try an alternative library, e.g. https://www.boraji.com/jfreechart-pie-chart-example

Answer (score 0):

What about `org.isisaddons.wicket.wickedcharts:isis-wicket-wickedcharts-cpt:1.16.2`?

Comment: No, I added it, I still have the error on the imports